# Postgresql is returning results randomly after insertion

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I have started using postgresql recently and PGAdmin as the tool to manage it. Today I had to insert a row in between and to my surprise i did not find a GUI way to do it on PGAdmin. And now when I am querying the table it returns me the 2nd row 1st. Since I am new to this I do not know how to deal with this. Also please tell me if I no longer want to use postgresql and switch to mysql or some other is there a specific way to export my databases.

Comment: Do you have an `ORDER` clause? Because if you don't, the order is unspecified. I have seen the order change after `INSERT`s as well.

Comment: So if I have to traverse through the relation from top to bottom then I have to use the ORDER clause every time?

Comment: If you want to have a specific order, yes.

Comment: There is no such thing as the "top" or the "bottom" of a relational table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  SQL result sets are *unordered*, unless you have an `order by` clause.

I would strongly suggest that you have a serial column in the table that is used as a primary key.  One advantage is that you get the insert order.  Then, you can retrieve the results using:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by <serial column goes here>;
```

You can only depend on the ordering in the result set when you have an `order by` clause in the query.